# eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented - spinner

Tags: android, list, implementation, egl

I'm creating an application and implemented an expandable list and a few buttons into an activity.  After setting up the classes for the expandable list, I'm getting an eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented error. As far as I can tell, it has only affected my spinners which have no items anymore. This is the case in emulation and on a phone.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have your problem too, in addition I face this error whenever I tap on spinner